# How do you refer to some variables in the workspace, through a different variable?

Tags: matlab, variables, null

For example, when using `parfor`, it doesn't let you clear variables inside due to "Transparency Violation Error".
One suggestion I found was to set the variables I want to `[]` instead of `clear -except var1, var2`. But I'd like to evidently set them all at once, because I'm only interested in keeping a few, the rest should be cleared/set to `[]`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What you could possibly do is if you know **exactly** what variables are available in your workspace, you can loop through and run through a whole bunch of `eval` statements and set those variables you want to `[]` and leave the ones you want untouched.

Comment: @rayryeng: eval has the same limitations.

Comment: @Calin O.: About what types of variables are we takling (temporary/sliced/broadcast)? If you are not familiar with these terms, please add a code example to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to `"empty"` some of the variables whose names are known and keep the rest as they are.

Now, you have asked how to refer to those variables in the `workspace`, to which one thing that came to my mind was using a `cell array with the cells as those variable names`.
Next, task was to empty those variables, to which the only thing that struck me was using `eval` which was also suggested in the comments to the question. I understand `eval` is frowned upon, but I don't see any other way out and I would love to see someone else suggesting some other alternative solution to evade this. Next, to make `eval` work with all the chosen variables, I went to `cellfun`.

Everything must be get clear with the code -

```
%// Variables for demo
var1 = 2;
var2 = 22;
a3 = 5;
a4 = [2 7];
a5 = [7 2.3 56];

c1 = {'var1','var2'} %// cell array of variable names to be "emptied"

%// Choose the variable names that are actually present in the workspace
allvars = who;
c1 = allvars(ismember(allvars,c1)) 

%// Empty the choosen variables
cellfun(@eval,strcat(c1,'=[];'))
```

Comment: +1... mainly because this is the idea I had in mind.... and the only idea that I had, even if it is frowned upon.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! Yeah I don't see anything else for this case. Let's see if it works with OP too!